# How to create a new data table that groups by variables in R

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate, dplyr

I have a data frame that contains information on patients and their attendance status at hospitals.  I want to create a new dataframe from the original that will list their number of appointments, number of missed and number attended

For example, my starting data table looks like:

```
Patient      Status
A            Attended
A            Attended
A            Attended
B            Did not attend
C            Did not attend
D            Attended
D            Did not attend
```

I would like the output table to look like

```
Patient      Number of appointments  Number attended     Number missed
A            3                              3                   0
B            1                              0                   1 
C            1                              0                   1
D            2                              1                   1
```

I tried having a look through previous answers, but couldnt quite find my answer.  I think I might have to do something with aggregate function but I couldnt figure it out

Comment: Ideally you need to have tried something yourself. If you dont know how, try google first. Then try and solve the problem. If the code you have still doesnt work.... THEN post a question here. Include a clear description of the problem.. Include the code that isnt working - see here Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - tell us what behaviour you're expecting and what you're actually getting - and include any errors and tell us where they are. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks David, I will do that next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,.(Number_of_appointments = .N, 
              Number_Attended = sum(Status== "Attended"),
              Number_Missed = sum(Status == "Did not attend")) , Patient]
```

Or use `dcast`

```
dcast(setDT(df1)[, N:=.N, Patient], Patient+N~Status, value.var='Status', length)
#   Patient N Attended Did not attend
#1:       A 3        3              0
#2:       B 1        0              1
#3:       C 1        0              1
#4:       D 2        1              1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
abc <- data.frame(Patient = c(rep("A",3),"B","C",rep("D",2)), 
Status = c(rep("Attended",3),
  rep("Did not attend",2),"Attended","Did not attend"))

abc[,c("Patient","Status")] <-apply(abc[,c("Patient","Status")] ,2, as.character)

  Patient         Status
       A       Attended
       A       Attended
       A       Attended
       B Did not attend
       C Did not attend
       D       Attended
       D Did not attend


for( i in unique(abc$Patient)){
  abc$Number_of_appointments[abc$Patient==i] <-length(abc$Status[abc$Patient==i])
  abc$Number_attended[abc$Patient==i] <- sum(grepl("Attended",abc$Status[abc$Patient==i])%in%"TRUE")
  abc$Number_missed[abc$Patient==i] <- sum(!grepl("Attended",abc$Status[abc$Patient==i])%in%"TRUE")
}

abc$Status <-NULL
abc1<-abc[!duplicated(abc$Patient),]

  Patient         Status Number_of_appointments Number_attended Number_missed
       A       Attended                      3               3             0
       B Did not attend                      1               0             1
       C Did not attend                      1               0             1
       D       Attended                      2               1             1
```